Сделать кнопку активной в диалоговом окне (win32)
При запуске бинарного приложения появляется стартовое окно с тремя неактивными кнопками. Как можно сделать любую кнопку активной и как повесить прерывание по её нажатию?
Visual Studio, Spy++, WinDbg установлены.

Активировать можно в любом редакторе ресурсов, только это ничего не даст вам, т.к. нужно искать причину.
